# How to save feed output to file

Tags: php, zend-framework, rss

I have the following code which based on http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.feed.writer.html:

```
$out = $feed->export('rss');
```

I want to save ouput from $out to the new file.
How can I do it?

I know about fwrite, but I'm looking for something otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with ZF2 and I can't find any docs about this, but a quick and dirty solution would be using output buffering

```
ob_start();
$feed->export('rss');
$feed_data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents('yourfile.xml', $feed_data);
```

This would prevent the XML from being sent to the browser by catching the output, saving it into a variable, and then clearing the output buffer so you scripts continues working as usual

Comment: Export returns the data, so you can just do `file_put_contents('yourfile.xml', $feed->export('rss'));`

Comment: I didn't see that clear in the docs. Seems only logical, though.